# Best way to prove this?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm just learning real analysis from Stephen Abbott's book, and one of the exercises is

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}$$
I have come up with the following proof:
Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary. For each $\epsilon$ choose $\mathcal{N}$ so that $\mathcal{N} > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$. This means for every $n \ge \mathcal{N}$, it follows:

$$n > \frac{2}{\epsilon} \mbox{ which is equivelant to } \frac{2}{n} < \epsilon$$
and thus:

$$
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
            \frac{2}{n} &= \frac{2}{n} \cdot \frac{n^2}{n^2} < \epsilon \\
            &\implies \frac{2n^2}{n^3} < \epsilon\\
            &\implies \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} < \epsilon\\
            &\implies \left| \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 0 \right| < \epsilon
        \end{split}  
    \end{equation}
$$
And by definition of convergence, this is true.

Is there a faster way to prove this? By this I mean, is there an easier $\mathcal{N}$ or perhaps a different method that can solve this is fewer lines?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Do you need to use a direct $\epsilon$-$N$-proof? If you divide numerator and denominator with $n^3$ then you can just apply limits on numerator and denominator separately.

Comment: The limit as $n$ approaches ?

Comment: Please have a look at [Choosing a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144)

Comment: @md2perpe I have not studied the Order Limit Theorems yet, the book by Abbott implies this should be completed with an $\epsilon - \mathcal{N}$ proof

Comment: @JohnDouma Book notation without $n \to c$ implies $n \to \infty$, I've edited the question though haha

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like $\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}<\frac{2n^2}{n^3}=\frac{2}{n}$ and then use $\epsilon$-$\delta$ on the rightmost term.

Comment: I see, but doing it that way was a bit longer, is there any errors with my current proof?

Comment: It is alright but you have proved something different from what is being asked. And be careful that $\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} < \epsilon$ doesn't imply $\frac{2n^2+1}{n^3+3} < \epsilon$.

Comment: sorry, I have edited the proof, is it ok now?

Comment: Yes it is alright!

Comment: I should also rewrite my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. For $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $n > \max\{1,\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\}$: $$\left |\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}\right | < \frac{2n^2}{2n^3} = \frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon$$

Comment: I see $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$  implies $n > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, so why does $\mathcal{N}$ need to be defined as the maximum of $1$ or $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$?